# subscript out of bounds in R

Tags: r, regex, text-mining, stringr

I want to remove certain element from `names`.

`names` is a list of characters. After I run the following loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(names)){
  if((str_detect(names[[i]], "  Organisation Name")) || 
  (str_detect(names[[i]], "^ $")) || (str_detect(names[[i]], "^0$")) || 
  (str_detect(names[[i]], "^$"))  ){
   names[[i]] <- NULL
 }
}
```

I get an error. The error is:

> Error in names[[i]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I'm guessing that as you kill off elements of names, the "i" vector still iterates to the original length, and so you wind up grabbing an out-of-bounds element.  Maybe try iterating backwards from length(names):1?  Even if I'm guessing right, @MrFlick is right about reproducible examples and you should edit the question for posterity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code illustrating what I think is going on based on my comment.

```
names <- lapply(1:5, list)
for (i in 1:length(names)) {
  names[[i]] <- NULL
  print(sprintf('Length is now %d, i is now %i', length(names), i))
  print(names[[i]])
}
```

This outputs

```
[1] "Length is now 4, i is now 1"
[[1]]
[1] 2

[1] "Length is now 3, i is now 2"
[[1]]
[1] 4

[1] "Length is now 2, i is now 3"
Error in names[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

If you iterate backwards, as with `for (i in length(names):1)` that might work

Answer (score 1):

Since you are *filtering* the data, I suggest you use the built in filtering functions, such as `grepl`.

Combine all your regexpa into one, for better performance and compactness.

Comment: Thanks, @Anony-Mousse. That's true.